# Почему криво считаются загруженные img на странице html javascript

Tags: javascript

Я пытаюсь в прелоадер вывести количество загруженных `img`, которые есть в данный момент, сигнализируя о процессе загрузки данных. Много не нужно, просто показать, что сейчас грузится, и что скоро "вот это" скроется. Плюс прикрутил прогресс-бар, в котором, когда изображение загрузилось, прибавляет ширину рассчитанную по формуле: `100% / на кол-во изображений`. И в функции полученное число умножаю на кол-во загруженных img. Если количество равно 1, то получится 10%. 10 загруженных фото = 100%.

Почитав учебник на эти темы, у меня вышло что-то вроде этого:

```
<section class="preloader">
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    <article class="center">

        <div class="loader"></div>

        <section class="status">
            <div class="load interactive">
                <p>Загрузка структуры страницы:</p>
                <div class="spiner"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="load complete">
                <p>Загрузка ресурсов страницы:</p>
                <div class="spiner"></div>
                <div class="images_counter"></div>
            </div>              
        </section>
    </article>
</section>
```

JS

```
let spiner = document.querySelectorAll('.spiner'),
    preloader = document.querySelector('.preloader'),
    imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img'),
    counter = document.querySelector('.images_counter');




    counter.innerHTML = '(0 из ' + imgs.length + ')';

    preloader.children[0].style.width = '0%';

    document.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(document.readyState == 'interactive'){
            spiner[0].classList.add('done'); //это если дом загружен
            spiner[0].innerHTML = 'OK';
        }else if(document.readyState == 'complete'){
            spiner[1].classList.add('done');//это если вся стр загружена
            spiner[1].innerHTML = 'OK';
            // preloader.classList.add('is-hidden');// красиво скрываю и удаляю из дом

            // setTimeout(function(){
                // preloader.remove();
            // }, 1375)
        }

        //check loaded images

        let loaded_image = 1,
            width_bar = 100 / imgs.length;

        for(let i = 0; i <= imgs.length; i++){
            imgs[i].onload = function(){
                counter.innerHTML = '(' + loaded_image + ' из ' + imgs.length + ')';//вывожу сколько загружено из столько-то
                preloader.children[0].style.width = width_bar * loaded_image + '%';//это и есть прогресс бар
                loaded_image++;//как бы наращиваю число загруженных картинок
            }
        }
    }
```

Я пытаюсь добиться мини-процесса загрузки ресурсов и написал код, он работал очень хорошо, но после попытался написать по-другому и все испортил. `ctrl + z` так сильно назад меня не вернул, и знаний не хватает понять так ли я делаю. Теперь при запуске он либо слишком быстро показывает загрузку, либо не показывает, либо доходит до определенной цифры загруженного `img` и стоит почему-то. Чего стоит, кого ждет - не знаю. Можете подсказать или направить на ошибки?

Я так и не понял, как здесь грузить так, чтобы у вас здесь открывался и показывал, что там у меня работает или нет. Короче я выложил [вот тут](https://jsfiddle.net/hn3btpy9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько моментов:

- для Вашего JS кода важна опция jsFiddle `Load Type`. Она должна быть установлена на `No wrap - bottom of <body>`. По умолчанию там `On Load`. В этом случае событие `onreadystatechange` вызвано не будет; [image: Скриншот из jsFiddle]
- цикл навешивания `onload` обработчиков следует вывести из обработчика `onreadystatechange`;
- в цикле - ошибка в условии завершения. Должно быть `<`, а не `<=`

Результат - ниже и в [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nsmcan/0Lvnydg8/)

```js
let spiner = document.querySelectorAll('.spiner'),
  preloader = document.querySelector('.preloader'),
  imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img'),
  counter = document.querySelector('.images_counter');

counter.innerHTML = '(0 из ' + imgs.length + ')';

preloader.children[0].style.width = '0%';

let loaded_image = 1,
  width_bar = 100 / imgs.length;

for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  imgs[i].onload = function() {
    counter.innerHTML = '(' + loaded_image + ' из ' + imgs.length + ')';
    preloader.children[0].style.width = width_bar * loaded_image + '%';
    loaded_image++;
  }
}

document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (document.readyState == 'interactive') {
    spiner[0].classList.add('done');
    spiner[0].innerHTML = 'OK';
  } else if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
    spiner[1].classList.add('done');
    spiner[1].innerHTML = 'OK';
    // preloader.classList.add('is-hidden');

    // setTimeout(function(){
    // preloader.remove();
    // }, 1375)
  }

  //check loaded images

}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.preloader {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.preloader.is-hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 375ms;
}


/* Progress */

.progress-bar {
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2196F3, #FFEB3B, #f44336);
  transition: 1375ms;
}

.center {
  margin: auto;
}

.loader,
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.loader {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
  border-left: 2px solid #2196F3;
  animation: loader 600ms linear infinite;
}

.loader:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 6px;
  width: 112px;
  height: 112px;
  border-left: 2px solid #FFEB3B;
  animation-duration: loader 1200ms linear infinite;
}

.loader:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 12px;
  width: 104px;
  height: 104px;
  border-left: 2px solid #f44336;
  animation: loader 600ms linear infinite;
}

@keyframes loader {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.status,
.load {
  display: flex;
  text-transform: none;
}

.status {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #555;
}

.spiner {
  margin: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border-left: 1px solid #f44336;
  animation: loader 375ms linear infinite;
}

.spiner.done {
  border: 0;
  color: #4CAF50;
  animation: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="preloader">
  <div class="progress-bar"></div>
  <article class="center">

    <div class="loader"></div>

    <section class="status">
      <div class="load interactive">
        <p>Загрузка структуры страницы:</p>
        <div class="spiner"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="load complete">
        <p>Загрузка ресурсов страницы:</p>
        <div class="spiner"></div>
        <div class="images_counter"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </article>
</section>

<div style="display: none;">
  <img src="http://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554545416-f8bfd9f59149?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=80">
  <img src="http://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554545286-68f95b3405ad?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60">
  <img src="http://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554545286-0014de69f57b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60">
  <img src="http://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554545286-e18ec21129b4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60">
  <img src="http://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554226321-24fdcddd5a55?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60">
  <img src="http://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554215352-d03d9deba830?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60">
  <img src="http://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554024104-9a372355b0b8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60">
</div>
```

### Добавлено

Нашел интересный сайт - `http://deelay.me/1000?http://mysite.com/image.gif`
Работает как прокси, задерживая загрузку ресурса на заданное количество миллисекунд.

Так что пример сейчас работает красиво! Но только в jsFiddle.

Среда моделирования на Stack Overflow принудительно заменяет http линки на https, поэтому пришлось убрать задерживающий прокси из примера кода...

Comment: Спасибо. Здесь почему-то не работает, но на другом ресурсе все хорошо кажется. Я правда не понял, где вы используете опцию load type или что Вы имели ввиду? Кажется Вы вынесли цикл и поправили его в одном месте, больше я не заметил изменений. Вроде так

Comment: Из исправлений - именно те, что Вы увидели. А насчет load type - это опция на jsFiddle - я добавил скриншот в ответ.

Comment: Благодарю......